# Assigning multiple function outputs to separate columns in pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, assign

I have a function with 3 outputs, and for the sake of efficiency, I would like to apply the function to all rows in my dataframe. Currently I am calling the function 3 times, once for each column/ouput, but I would like to call the function once and save all 3 outputs to 3 separate columns. But currently I cannot find a way to assign the outputs.

Ideally I would want something like...

```
df2[col1, col2, col3] = function(x,y)
```

Here is my current code.

```
def getTextureMetrics(row,abb_name):
#tic=time.time()
d2=row[[col for col in ds.columns if abb_name+'_2' in col]].values #offset distance 2
maxOffset2=maxDiff(d2)
d6=row[[col for col in ds.columns if abb_name+'_6' in col]].values #offset distance 6
maxOffset6=maxDiff(d6)
d10=row[[col for col in ds.columns if abb_name+'_10' in col]].values #offset distance 10
maxOffset10=maxDiff(d10)
#print(tic-time.time())
return maxOffset2, maxOffset6, maxOffset10

for abb_name in unique(abb_names):
tic=time.time()
exec('df2["'+abb_name+'_2"]=df2.apply (lambda row: getTextureMetrics(row,abb_name)[0],axis=1)' )
exec('df2["'+abb_name+'_6"]=df2.apply (lambda row: getTextureMetrics(row,abb_name)[1],axis=1)' )
exec('df2["'+abb_name+'_10"]=df2.apply (lambda row: getTextureMetrics(row,abb_name)[2],axis=1)' )
```

Comment: H Anders, just friendly advice, but it helps to frame the title as a question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with the `result_type='expand'`:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: function(x), result_type='expand', axis=1)
```

Example:

```
def function(x):
    return x.col1 + '_2' , x.col2 + '_6', x.col3 + '_10'

d = { 'col1' : ['John', 'Mark Dupont', 'Max'],
      'col2' : ['John Doe', 'Mark 40', 'Edith'],
      'col3' : ['John Doe 40', 'Something', 'Edith']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df = df.apply(lambda x: function(x), result_type='expand', axis=1)
df

0   1   2
0   John_2  John Doe_6  John Doe 40_10
1   Mark Dupont_2   Mark 40_6   Something_10
2   Max_2   Edith_6 Edith_10
```